# Area between curves $e^{2x}$

Tags: integration

Can someone help me with this problem please?
It says:

> Find $k$ so that:
>   $$0 < k < 5/2$$
>   and the area between $y=e^{2x}$, $y=e^{-2x}$ and $y=k$ results in $[ 10\ln(5/2) - 2/5 ]$.

I started looking for intersections between $y=k$ and those $2$ other curves and I got: 
 $x_1 = \frac{\ln(k)}{2}$ 
 and 
 $x_2 = -\frac{\ln(k)}{2}$ 

After that i tried to find this: 
 $\int_{-\frac{\ln(k)}{2}}^0 k-e^{-2x} + \int_0^{\frac{\ln(k)}{2}}k-e^{2x}$

I'm stuck there...

Comment: So Integrate . . .

Comment: Yes i did that and i get  1 - k + k log(k)...
but i don't know how to proceed with this
1 - k + k log(k) = 10ln(5/2) - 2/5

Comment: My answer for the first is $$\int_{-\ln(k)/2}^{0}(k-e^{-2x})dx=kx+\frac12e^{-2x}\Big|_{-\ln(k)/2}^{0}=\frac12+\frac12k\ln k-\frac{k}{2}$$ Right.?

Comment: Yeah that's right, when yo do the other part the one that goes from 0 to ln(k)/2 you get the same...

Comment: And their addition.$1+k\ln k$.?

Comment: No, their adition to 1 + _k_ ln _k_ - _k_

Comment: I solved $1+k\ln k-k=10\ln\dfrac52-\dfrac25$ with mathematica and answer was $k\sim7.57...$ so part of your problem is wrong.

Comment: the other issue there is that y=k curve can be above or under y=1 and at that point the 2 other curves intersect and the integration should change...

Comment: Can you write your problem in English, please?

Comment: In this case the answer is the same $1+k\ln k-k$. Not different $k$ where is.